# How to know if a job before a spring batch job is finished

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch.

But, there is one problem.

It is that the deployment continues to occupy resources without being terminated due to any errors.

Therefore, it is necessary to verify that the job has been properly terminated and that the resource has been returned before the job is executed.

We also want to know how to return the resource and re-enforce it if the resource is occupied without normal shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Spring batch provides a table structure to maintain JOB execution states.

[See - Schema](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/schema-appendix.html)

It will help to complete your requirement

Comment: I'm using the waternon batch metable.

However, a column in the corresponding batch_job_execution table is INSERT as shown below.

[STATUS : STARTED |
EXIT_CODE : UNKOWN |
END_TIME : null]

There is a problem that the job on the day of execution has not been executed since then.

Comment: Can you print exist status at schedular and provide logs for same

Comment: 2020-01-05 00:19:00,267 [pool-33-thread-1] [INFO] - SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(132) | Job: [FlowJob: [name=statisticsJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{date=Sun Jan 05 00:19:00 KST 20
20}]
2020-01-05 00:19:02,429 [pool-33-thread-1] [INFO] - SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(139) | Executing step: [statisticsJobStep]

--> this is my job log. there is no exception log

Comment: Need to know output of below code **JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(myJob, jobParameters);
LOGGER.debug("Scheduler Completed " + execution.getExitStatus());**

Comment: Okay, I'll test the job to get the same data.  
Is there a new method or logic that returns a job?